# Abraham–Lorentz force, electron-positron annihilation, and energy conservation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

When a particle is experiencing jerk, it experiences a force in the direction of the jerk. This is why a particle moving in a sinusoidal motion and a particle going in a circle lose energy. The Abraham–Lorentz force opposes the motion of the particle and as a result it loses kinetic energy. This doesn't seem to occur during electron-positron annihilation though. The jerk would be in the direction of travel for the electron. This would mean that the Abraham–Lorentz force would be adding energy to the electron and positron as they travel closer to each other. This would be the case if they are traveling in a straight line towards each other. If they were spiraling in on each other(which is probably how electrons and positrons usually annihilate) then the electron would be able to lose energy to the circular motion. Is my understanding of all this correct because it seems like energy wouldn't be conserved in a heads on electron-positron annihilation?

Comment: If you're talking about electron-positron annihilation, you really need to do so in a QFT context.

Comment: I don't know much about that so I don't think I'd be able to do that.

Comment: Then I would hold off on applying classical electrodynamics to a non-classical situation.